# No module named 'oauthlib' Python 3.4

Tags: python, importerror

I can't import requests_oauthlib, I've tried looking for a fix, but have had no luck.  When I try to import it I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/steven/PycharmProjects/howareyou/questions.py", line 4, in <module>

    import requests_oauthlib

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .oauth1_auth import OAuth1

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py", line 6, in <module>

    from oauthlib.common import extract_params

ImportError: No module named 'oauthlib'
```

`import sys; print (sys.path)` gives me:

```
['/home/steven/PycharmProjects/howareyou',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/steven/PycharmProjects/howareyou',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/home/steven/howareyouve/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages']
```

The actual package is located in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages as are all of my packages, and I can import everything else, it's just seems to be oauthlib. I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling as well.

Comment: what'd you use to install/uninstall it?

Comment: did you installed it via `pip`?

Comment: I've been using pip, I tried apt-get using a method in another thread and it didn't do anything...

Comment: try running in terminal `pip3 freeze`. Can you see oauthlib there? You must have installed it in python2 environment. If `oauthlib` is not there try installing it via `pip3 install oauthlib`. then run your script.

Comment: It looks like it's installed. 

It says oauthlib==1.0.3

Comment: mine is solved by @ManishGupta comment, use pip3 instead of pip

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I figured it out finally.  It looks like there were two copies of oauthlib installed.  I installed oauthlib using pip to /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages, and at sometime or another oauthlib was also installed to the /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

I was able to simply use:

```
apt-get remove python3-oauthlib
```

and everything seems to work again